# About a property of weighted Sobolev spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, sobolev-spaces

If we define the weighted Sobolev norm as
$$
\|f\|_{H^{s,k}(\mathbb R^n)} := \|(1+|x|^2)^{k/2} (\sqrt{1-\Delta})^s f \|_{L^2(\mathbb R^n)}
$$
where $f(x):\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ and $\Delta$ is Laplacian, $k\ge 0,s >0$,
then does the following property
$$
\| f\|_{H^{s,0}(\mathbb R^n)} \le C\| f\|_{H^{s,k}(\mathbb R^n)}
$$
hold for any $k>0$?

Comment: Have you spent any time thinking about this at all? The factor $(1+|x|^2)^{k/2}$ is $\ge 1$ pointwise.

Comment: I'm tempted to vote to close...